# Change commit message for specific commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rewrite-history, git-amend

Note: similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/647991), but with some important changes.

I have the following function to rewrite the date of a commit, given the commit id:

```
rewrite-commit-date () {
    local commit="$1"
    local newdate="$2"
    newdate="$(date -R --date "$newdate")"
    echo ">>>> Rewriting commit $commit date: $newdate"
    git filter-branch --env-filter \
        "if test \$GIT_COMMIT = '$commit'
         then
             export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
             export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
             GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='$newdate'
             GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='$newdate'
         fi" &&
    rm -fr "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/refs/original/"
}
```

I am trying to implement a similar function `rewrite-commit-message` to change the commit message. What I want is:

1. The function `rewrite-commit-message` accepts two parameters: the `commit_id`, and the `new_commit_message`
2. There is no need to know the old commit message: having the `commit_id` is enough to know which commit to change
3. No `git commit --amend`, since this is related to old commits (not necessarily to the most recent commit)
4. No worries about rewriting history and the master repo: I am working in a feature branch, and I am allowed to do `git push -f`
5. I would like to use [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for this, but I am not sure how to:

   - apply the change to a specific commit: the `test` used in the `rewrite-commit-date` function is used in `env-filter`, but I am not going to do `env-filter` here, since I do not want to change anything related to the commit environment, but the commit message.
   - how to force a commit message? The `--msg-filter` needs the original commit message. I do not care about the original commit message. Is there a `--force-msg-filter` or similar?

What I am looking for is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231177/647991), but with some caveats:

1. Do not apply the change to a range of commits, but to a specific commit
2. I do not care about the original commit message, since I want to completely overwrite it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This little script works given the following caveats:

1. This will rewrite your history from the commit to the tip of the branch. Because you stated in the question that this isn't a problem, then this qualifies.
2. Your commit is contained in the `master` branch. You can easily change this by passing the branch name as another parameter, but that commit *better* be in the branch. You should probably build in some validation for this, perhaps using [`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/4233593) or maybe [`git branch --all --contains <commit>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35015527/4233593)

Without further ado:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

change-commit-msg(){

  commit="$1"
  newmsg="$2"
  branch="master"

  git checkout $commit
  git commit --amend -m "$newmsg"
  git cherry-pick $commit..$branch
  git branch -f $branch
  git checkout $branch

}
```

## Demo

```
git init
echo init > a && git add . && git commit -m "init"
echo another > a && git commit -am "another"
echo lastly > a && git commit -am "lastly"
git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
```

> ```
> * bca608c (HEAD -> master) lastly
> * 4577ab5 another
> * b3d018c init
> ```

```
change-commit-msg 4577ab5 "something else"
```

> ```
> * c7d03bb (HEAD -> master) lastly
> * 3ec2c3e something else
> * b3d018c init
> ```