# How to get branch name when running pipeline on tag?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I run pipeline from a tag (let's say `v1.0.0`) on a branch (let's say `staging`).
My output file is created with `${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.apk`. 
The result is a file named `MyProject-v1.0.0.apk`.

I wish add branch name in the output filename to get `MyProject-staging-v1.0.0.apk`.

[From the gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), i could use `CI_COMMIT_TAG` and `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` like this `${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}.apk`.
But the documentation says:

> CI_COMMIT_BRANCH : The commit branch name. Present only when building
>   branches.
>
> CI_COMMIT_TAG : The commit tag name. Present only when building tags.

So how to get the branch name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [find which branch a tag is part of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806668/6309).

The issue is: a tag can be referenced (part of the history of) multiple branch.

So, [as in here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/31305#note_28580169), your `gitlab.yml` could call a script setting that branch ([settings an environment variable](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27921#note_23059897)), provided you have a convention in place to select the branch you want out of the (possibly) more than one branch which could refer said tag.

Comment: Is there also a gitlab variable that always references the branch name, even if the pipeline is triggered on a tag?

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer I don't see one. You could ask a separate question, to be sure (and do add details about your setup, like OS and GitLab version).

Comment: I could solve my problem with your answer and have assigned an env var. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -3):

There is an env var called which references either the branch name or tag name called `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`

Comment: Have you seriously read and understand the question?

Comment: This would be the tag name according to the docs: "The branch or tag name for which project is built." So it would not hold the branch name in this case but the tag name. It is a nice multi use variable, but does not fit the bill for this issue.