# Gitlab: Allow tag creation from specific branch only

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there a way or setting in gitlab by which I can allow users to create tags from pre-approved branches??

In other words, if I try to create a new tag on Gitlab, I get specific list of Git revisions for 'create from' field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a feature that exists in GitLab.

And, as far as git is concerned, tags are not associated with branches at all, only commits. So when a tag is pushed, you can never be certain of any one specific branch having been used.

As described in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61917282/5747944):

> You can [find which branch a tag is part of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806668/6309).
>
> The issue is: a tag can be referenced (part of the history of) multiple branch.

So, you *can* find which branch(es) a tag belongs to. The closest thing to this may be to have a job in tag pipelines to verify the tagged commit exists on one of the pre-approved branches. However, this won't affect any dropdowns in the GitLab UI. It also won't prevent the tag push to begin with unless you use a [pre-receive hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html) (self-managed GitLab only).

You might choose to include a CI job like this:

```yaml
check_tags:
  stage: .pre
  # only allow tag pipelines to succeed if the tagged commit is
  # in an acceptable branch
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script:
    - allowed_branches='(main|release\/*)'
    # get all the branches for this tag
    - branches="$(find-branches "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}")" # you implement this
    - |
      for branch in $branches; do
          if [[ $branch =~ $allowed_branches ]]; then
              exit 0  # branch is allowed, exit gracefully
          fi
      done
      # tag does not exist in any allowed branch
      exit 1
```

You might even make the job remove the tag from the repo, if you really wanted.

If you had the same logic in a pre-receive hook, it could prevent the tag from being created.