# How to merge request a git branch created from an upstream tag

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request, merge-request

I created a new local branch from a tag contained in the upstream repo (`git checkout -b mybranch upstreamTag`). I pushed my local branch to my forked repo (`git push -u origin mybranch`). Now how can I submit a GitLab merge request to the upstream repo? I know how to do it if my branch had been created from an upstream branch, but how to reference the upstream tag?

Comment: The tag should be contained in a branch. Use that branch as the target branch.

Comment: To find the branch associated with a tag is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806448/git-how-to-find-out-on-which-branch-a-tag-is). Many thanks!