# How to use git filter-branch to take some large files out of the master branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm a bit of a beginner in git, mainly relying on GUI tools like Source Tree, so bear with me, please!

In our git repo, we have multiple products that rely on a very similar core codebase. We achieve this by having a branch per product. When we first started development, we hadn't established this as a workflow, so our branch history looks a bit like this:

```
 master
   |
B  |  C
 \ | /
  \|/
   |
   |  A
   | /
   |/
   2
   |
   |
   1
   |
   |
```

A, B, and C are product-specific branches, with A being our first product for a client.

**The problem**

Unfortunately, around point (1) we were already working on A, and had already started to commit a large number of .png files (around 100MB worth), but didn't think to branch it off as a separate project yet. I've tried pruning out these large files from the repo in B and C (as well as the master branch), but of course they're still in the git commit history between points (1) and (2).

So, is there any way I could re-write the history, so that branch A actually starts at point 1, and move all files specific to that product into that branch? Thankfully it should be pretty easy to filter out the files associated with product A, since they're mostly in a separate directory.

Theoretically, the master branch would only need to be ~10MB since it would mainly consist of code, meaning that people could check out only a specific product branch, and only download the files from github that they actually need.

Thanks!

***Edit***: Note, this is a similar question: [git: Split history of some files into a separate branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278264/git-split-history-of-some-files-into-a-separate-branch)

Comment: No... what specifically would you recommend I rebase? How?

Comment: I don't see your exact requirements. You could use rebase to move commits around the tree. Read documentation about rebase and try to match it with your requirements. Maybe you need interactive rebase to manually sort out commits.

Comment: The end result you want is: 1) `master` contains no png commits; 2) the png commits are entirely in `A`; 3) `A` is branched off the current tip of `master`, or commit `2`?

Comment: 1) Almost, yeah. Actually I just don't want master to have anything in the folder named "A", including code and PNGs (happens to be the name of the branch too) 2) Yeah. 3) A is branched off commit 2, but I want A' to branch off at commit 1, and have it include all commits between 1 and 2 beforehand. And then master to include 1->2 without anything in folder "A". Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, backup!

Then, do this:

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -rf PATH/TO/FILE-OR-FOLDER' HEAD
```

And then

```
git gc --aggressive
```

Via http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2009/04/merging_two_unr.html

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
git checkout A
git rebase 2 --onto 1
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why but that didn't work for me? Both when I tried replacing "2" and "1" with the SHAs and when I tried creating named branches. Also, perhaps I didn't make it clear, but there are lots of commits between points 1 and 2 that are both A-specific and non-A-specific, but they should be fairly easy to filter, since all A-specific files are in a directory called "A". Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, I was responding to the question "is there any way I could re-write the history, so that branch A actually starts at point 1". I tested this command with some of my repositories, and it worked. How exactly did it fail for you?

Comment: I got the SHA1s for the commits, and entered: `$ git rebase 149c2e1b4f252e8bdb636997803a54f8227edc71 --onto ca44f4503ea72e649e7ebeeb6a3428ddd1e43e1d`. Output was: `Usage: git rebase [--interactive | -i] [-v] [--force-rebase | -f] [--no-ff] [--onto <newbase>] (<upstream>|--root) [<branch>] [--quiet | -q]`

Comment: I'm unsure of exactly how this would help exactly anyway, given that the series of commits between 1 and 2 are direct continuous ancestors of branch A?

Comment: Which version of git are you using? I use 1.7.12, and a line like `git rebase f79d8b152629466f9195fd78bacd7f614ad5e9b9 --onto c3a7fa28d916f0ad6194b15e3484efcf339f64bd` works correctly. Maybe in older git you would need to spell it as `git rebase --onto ca44f4503ea72e649e7ebeeb6a3428ddd1e43e1d 149c2e1b4f252e8bdb636997803a54f8227edc71`.

Comment: As for how it would help, it transplants all the commits between 2 and A onto 1, and sets A to point to the result. That sounds equivalent to "re-write the history so that branch A actually starts at point 1" that you requested, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with my on this! My git version is 1.7.5.4, but your second syntax worked... although it didn't quite give me the result I was expecting I'm afraid! I think I'm maybe not explaining the problem well enough. Between points 1 and 2 there are lots of commits, and they're a mixture of things - some contributing to the main codebase, and some contributing to project A. Are you suggesting that this rebase should be done as a first step, then I should filter the master branch to remove everything relating to A?